# What quantity changes when the signal is amplified without changing SNR in this case?

Tags: adc

This is a conceptial question and I want o ask via an example in my mind. So I neglect any other factors which are possible for the sake of simplification. Let’s assume an analog signal through a channel can handle 1V variation and has a noise level of 1mV.

And lets assume this analog signal will be sampled by a 10 bit ADC which has 10V input range.

We can directly couple this 1V signal and sample by the ADC or we can amplify the signal by 10 and match it to the ADC range.

If we assume the SNR remains the same before and after the amplification, what do we obtain better by matching the signal to the ADC range by amplification? What improves? Can you give some insight by using my example?

Comment: imagine a simple ADC that has an output range of 0 to 10 decimal ... apply a sine wave to the input ... what output will you see in each of the two scenarios that you described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a noise level of 1mV RMS.

A 10-bit ADC with a 10V input range will have quantization steps of 10mV.  *If* you treat the quantization as random (which may underestimate the effect) then that works out to an RMS noise of 3.46mV.  So your 1V signal, 1mV noise input signal will have a 60dB SNR going in to the ADC, and around a 49dB SNR coming out.

If, however, you amplify your signal to 10V signal + 10mV noise, then the total noise after quantization will be the equivalent of 11.6mV RMS, for a 60dB SNR going in and a 59.5dB SNR coming out.  That half a dB of degradation is practically negligible, unless you're locked in a specifications duel with a competing vendor.

Comment: Could you also tell how you calculate 3.46mV and 11.6mV? What are they?

Comment: Please ask "how do I model quantization noise" and I'll show how I get the 3.46mV figure.  The quick answer is that quantization noise can be treated as uniformly-distributed noise across one quantization step, and the RMS voltage of a voltage that's uniformly distributed from -5mV to +5mV is 3.46mV.

Comment: The 11.6mV comes from adding the mean-square voltages of 3.46mV and 10mV.  \$\sqrt{3.46^2 + 10^2} \simeq 11.6\$; hence the result.

Comment: Okay I will ask it as a new question I need a bit more explanation of this.

Comment: Here is the new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455425/how-do-i-model-quantization-noise

Comment: I reread your answer and now understood. You used q/sqrt(12) formula for rms noise value. In this example we neglected the noise added by amplification. The overall SNR reduced by amplification. In real however would the amplification also add noise? So it is not clear to me whether amplification is needed in practice. Thanks for the answer

Comment: The amplification would add noise, and should be taken into account in a real system design.  But it's fairly easy to get lower noise out of an amplifier than out of an ADC, and it wouldn't be uncommon with a bit of work to make the amplifier noise insignificant compared to the ADC noise.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the system's S/N will likely change if you amplify the signal (but stay within the linear range) to an ADC.  That's because the quantization noise of the ADC in relation to the signal will decrease.  The closer the signal's peak is to 10V, the more "steps" that are available to be used to represent the signal's levels between min and the new higher max.  The more steps available, the less the proportionate rounding or truncation errors, statistically.

The case where this would not be true is when the signal is stepped and all its levels match the current ADC quantization.